# Open root owned system files for reading with python

Tags: python, file-io, permissions

**The business case...**
The app server (Ubuntu/nginx/postgresql/python) that I use writes gzipped system log files as root to /var/log
I need to present data from these log files to users' browsers

**My approach**
I need to do a fair bit of searching and string manipulation server side so I have a python script that deals with the opening and processing and then returns a nicely formatted JSON result set. The python (cgi) script is then called using ajax from the web page.

**My problem**
The script works perfectly when called from the command line as SU but (...obviously) the file opening method I'm using ( gzip.open(filename) ) is failing when invoked as user www-data by the webserver.

**Other useful info**
The app server concerned is (contractually rather than physically) a bit of a black box - I have SU access, I can write scripts, I can read anything but I can't change file permissions, add additional python libs or or mess with config.
The subset of users who can would use this log extract also have the SU password so could be presented with a login dialog that I could pass to the script.

Given the restrictions I have, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to do this somewhat sensitive "su" work in a background process that is disconnected from the web.

Likely running via cron, this script would take the root owned log files, possibly change them to a format that the web-side code could deal with easily like loading them into a database, or merely unzipping them and placing them into a different location with slightly more laxed permissions.

Then the web-side code could easily have access to the data without having to jump through the "su" hoops.

From my perspective this plan does not seem to violate your contractual rules. The web server config, permissions, etc remain intact.

Comment: It's a possibility... The data presented doesn't have to be bang up to date so I guess I could cron it once per day. Have a +1 sir and I'll have a play.

Comment: Does the log contains sensitive information? Probably. If so copying them from one secure location to one easily accessible by the web server would be a [no-no](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/no-no) as of myself...

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. You should give a try to paramiko, allowing you to access a host (even "localhost") through SSH:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='jesse', password='lol')
```

As you have the opportunity to ask for a login/password, those would be the one provided by the user querying the log. Accessing the files is then just a matter or reading a file under SSH. And you have the opportunity to close the connection as soon as you have finished that "sensitive" work.